# Redirect website to a subfolder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my website http://example.com to http://example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/

I tried editing htaccess using below code

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder1/folder2/folder3/ [L]
```

But it redirects only till  - http://example.com/folder1/

what else should be edited?

Comment: What do you mean by `but it redirects only till folder1` ? Do you have other htaccess in `folder2` or `folder3` ? Also, do you want **every** url to be forwarded to `/folder1/folder2/folder3/` or only home page ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I want only homepage to get forwarded to this path. Dont want to alter other htaccess files !!

Comment: Ok but what error do you have ? You said `it redirects only till /folder1/` could you be clearer ?

Comment: @JustinIurman in the url bar it shows me http://example.com/folder1/ but styling is all screwed up. However if i change the lastline of htacess code to "RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder1/ [L]" ... it redirects to http://example.com/folder1/ and no issues with styling. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well first, i don't know why the url bar shows you `/folder1` since your rule is an internal rewrite (should show you home page instead). Then, your css problems are coming from the fact that you're using **relative** paths instead of **absolute** paths for all your ressources (css, js, images, href links, etc)

Comment: Your code does not support the problem you are having. This code will not cause a redirect.